# Bolt cms duplica mi path cuando llamo a mis css y mis js

Tags: javascript, php, css, twig, symfony3

Estoy usando `Bolt CMS` en una de mis paginas y al incluir mis archivos de estilo o mis `javascript` hay una parte del link que se duplica, entonces no encuentra los archivos.

En `Bolt` se utiliza `Symfony` así que los incluyo con `assets` como el siguiente:

```
{{ asset('css/bootstrap.css', 'theme') }}
```

Cuando lo corro tendría que llevarme a:

```
localhost/bolt/public/theme/base-2016/css/bootstrap.css
```

Pero en vez de eso me esta llevando a:

```
localhost/bolt/public/bolt/public/theme/base-2016/css/bootstrap.css
```

como ven la parte "`bolt/public`" se duplica.

La ubicación de "`theme`" la deje por defecto y cuando trate de cambiarla desde un archivo llamado `config.yml`, me ocurría algo parecido.

Comment: Pareciera estar mal configurado el `base_path` y/o `base_urls` para `assest`, [revisa esto](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#assets)

Comment: Claro en el archivo config.yml podes configurar "theme_path", que supuestamente solo debes modificarlo en caso de que pongas en otra carpeta los archivos(lo cual no he hecho ), pero tambien probé modificandolo y me sigue ocurriendo lo mismo. Ahora trataré con lo que me pasaste de symfony. Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Si llegas a solucionarlo, no te olvides de publicar la respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

La unica manera que encontre rapidamente de hacerlo funcionar fue poner links desde la raiz sin assets, asi:

```
<img src="/bolt/public/theme/metroProba/images/metroymedio.jpg" alt="Metro y Medio" /></a>
```